# Creating a bar chart using loops

Tags: c++

My assignment was to use an input file to create a bar chart. It should look something like this:

```
1930:***

1950: ******

1970 *****

etc
```

I have everything written up but it keeps showing something like this:

```
1930

1950

1970

: ***

:******

:****
```

I can't seem to get them to display properly. Heres my code so far:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variables 

    int inputNum;
    int year;
    ifstream inputFile;


    inputFile.open("People.txt");


    if (!inputFile)  // file did not open
    {
        cout << "Input file did not open" << endl;
        return 10;
    }

    for (int year = 1910; year <= 2010; year += 20)
        cout << year << endl;
    while (inputFile >> inputNum)
    {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < (inputNum / 1000); counter++)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about counting all the years first then printing the results later?

Comment: I’ve been trying that but it feels like the input file messes with the way printing the year works and the asterisks also miscount

Comment: You printed out all the years first, then printed the asterisks. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
cout << year << endl;
```

does not need a `endl` at the end. Remove it so you just have:

```
cout << year;
```

Comment: when i remove the endl; all my numbers mush together

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with `std::map`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {

    std::fstream input_file("test.txt");
    std::map<int, int> years;
    std::string temp;

    while(input_file >> temp){

        //add if it doesnt exist, otherwise, increment it
        (years.find(std::stoi(temp)) == years.end()) ? years[std::stoi(temp)] = 1 : years[std::stoi(temp)]++;

    }

    for(auto i = years.begin(); i != years.end(); i++){

        std::cout << i->first << ": ";
        for(int j = 0; j < i->second; j++){
            std::cout << "*";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample txt file:

```
1930
1930
1930
1950
1950
1950
```

Output:

```
1930 ***
1950 ***
```

This will take any year in the file, if you only want certain years, you can easily just put extra statements to check

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt explain it correctly. The file contains number of people  and im supposed to sort it by year

Comment: @AndrewLin can you give an example of the file?

Comment: It’s a text file that goes 2000 3000 5000 7000 8000 9000 in descending order